# Comparing 2 strings

Tags: php, string, compare

I have a php script that's not working correctly.

when i test it using strcmp it returns 0 at the right time but the if statement still returns false.

Contents of keywords.php

```
<?php $cat_array = array("All Deals","Arts & Crafts","Automotive","Dental","Education & Training","Entertainment","Fashion","Fitness & Health","Floral","Fun & Adventure","Home & Garden","Pets","Photography","Restaurants","Spa & Beauty","Sports","Subscriptions","Tours & Attractions","Trade Shows","Travel","Workshops");
$cat_nav_array = array("alldeals","arts_crafts","automotive","dental","education_training","entertainment","fashion","fitness_health","floral","fun_adventure","home_garden","pets","photography","restaurants","spa_beauty","sports","subscriptions","tours_attractions","tradeshows","travel","workshops");
```

?>

php code for main page

```
 <?php 
        require_once("keywords/keywords.php");
        $count = 0;
        $category = $_GET['category'];
        foreach ($cat_array as $link)
        {
            $count++;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
        {
            $link = $cat_nav_array{$i};
            $text = $cat_array{$i};

            if ($category === $link) 
            {
            ?>
                <li><a class="ch_selected" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/chunky/others/?category=<?php echo $link?>" title="View all Deals from <?php echo $text ?>"><?php echo $text?></a></li>
            <?php 
            } 
            else
            {?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/chunky/others/?category=<?php echo $link ?>" title="View all Deals from <?php echo $text ?>"><?php echo $text?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
        } ?>
```

Working code:

```
    <?php 
        require_once("keywords/keywords.php");
        $count = 0;
        $category = strtolower($_GET['category']);
        foreach ($cat_array as $link)
        {
            $count++;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
        {
            $link = $cat_nav_array{$i};
            $text = $cat_array{$i};

            $same = strcmp($link, $category);

            if ($same != 0) 
            {
            ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/chunky/others/?category=<?php echo $link?>" title="View all Deals from <?php echo $text ?>"><?php echo $text?></a></li>
            <?php 
            } 
            else
            {?>
                <li class="ch_selected"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/chunky/others/?category=<?php echo $link ?>" title="View all Deals from <?php echo $text ?>"><?php echo $text?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
        } ?>
```

Comment: var_dump both of the variables before the if statement and post it here please.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't applying `strtolower`on `$_GET['category']`?

Comment: you are also missing an `echo` here `<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>`. it should be `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>`

Comment: i do not need strtolower on $_GET['catagory'] bcs it is already lowercase

Comment: just to be sure, you should `strtolower` also the _GET (as well as sanitize it, you never know if the user is going to manually write it and use all uppercase)

Comment: yea thats true. i added it in. When i do var_dump they are identical. same as when i use strcmp it returns 0

Comment: Ok i found the solution. I have updated my post with the correct/working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with `if ($catagory === $link)`.

Comment: If `==` gives false, then also `===` will give false as you compare type as well.  I agree with you that `===` is always better than `==`, but in this case it wnt solve the problem

Comment: [php manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) explaining the differences.

Answer (score 0):

try to do a `var_dump($link, $catagory)` right before the if line and see if the two vars are really the same.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off the answer but if i recall correctly that is not the way to compare strings. 
Please refer to this: http://www.phpcatalyst.com/php-compare-strings.php

Comment: There's no 'right way' or 'wrong way' to compare strings - it depends entirely on what you're trying to accomplish with the comparison. The only thing that might qualify as "wrong" is mistakenly using the assignment operator (=) instead of the comparison operator (==).

Comment: It doesn't matter in PHP, it matters in objective-based languages like Java or JavaScript, where `String` is an object, and comparing 2 strings will return false (as you are not comparing the values, you are comparing the pointer to the object in memory).

Comment: I don't know what is your 'right' and 'wrong' but as far as mine goes, if the operator doesn't compare string correctly (which in fact it doesn't) in my book it's the wrong way to do it. If the user looks at the link, i think he'll find what he needs.